# Android edittext span color not works if at the end of the line

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, android-spannable

I want to set span color on my EditText. It works fine when `str` is a single line or at the end of multi lined `str`. But if it is at the end of any of these inside lines, span does not color this part at the end of the line. How to solve that?

```
private void changeAddEtBackgroundColor(EditText et, int startIndex, String str) {
    Spannable raw = new SpannableString(et.getText());
    raw.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(Color.GREEN), startIndex, startIndex + str.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

    et.getEditableText().replace(0, et.length(), raw);
    et.setSelection(etDescPosition);
}
```

here is also this view in layout in case it is needed:

```
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_note_desc_value"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:gravity="top|start"
                android:hint="@string/enter_desc"
                android:maxLength="9000"
                android:textColor="?attr/myTextColor"
                android:textColorHint="?attr/myHintTextColor"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
```